# IBM Cloud API key could not be created

Tags: ibm-cloud, identity-management

To configure my Terraform to use my IBM cloud I need to generate an API key and Classic infrastructure key. This gives the error "API key could not be created".

What settings needs to be changed in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Your cloud administrator needs to add the IAM Identity Service - Service ID creator rights

[image]